# Can I create a test on play console where I can add testers by email, but they can download the app with their phone from the play store?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I would like to create a `test` on google play console, where I can specify the `testers by email`, like with internal testing, but only the added testers can `download` the app `WITH` their phone from the google play store?

Currently using internal testing requires the users to download the app from their computer, IF their phone is connected to their account. The app does not show up on the google play store on testers phones. If I have over 50 testers, going around the organization to help users download the app is not an efficient way in my opinion. I tried a beta test, which made my app go out to public, which I do not want. So, a test where I can allow only testers whos email i've added to the testers list to download the app from THEIR phone on the play store!

Answer (score 0):

Internal testing does not require downloading from a computer. And beta testing does not make the app go public. What makes you think these things?

Even if an internal testing app does not show up in search, you can email a link to it that users can open on their phones.

Comment: But that is still an extra step, why do that if the user could just download it from a phone. I figured out that I had to use Alpha testing, which allows people in the tester list to download the app from the play store with their phone.